# How can support iOS15 CarPlay from iOS12 app

Tags: ios, ios15, xcode13, carplay

I have an app that has car play feature and it supports ios12+.
Recently Apple releases iOS15 and old CarPlay is not working anymore. (looks like few apis became 'not working' status from 'deprecated' status.)

iOS15 CarPlay needs iOS13 style project setting using 'application scene manifest - CPTemplateApplicationSceneSessionRoleApplication' option from 'info.plist'
and iOS12 can not use ''application scene manifest'

This two conflict condition makes me frustrates.

I wonder if anyone solves this issue...

thanks

Comment: It's probably time to let the iOS 12 devices go.   They can always keep running your old version, but you are talking about devices from 2014 and earlier that can't run iOS13.

Comment: @Paulw11 the number of iOS12 users is not enough to drop them from the support list, so it is not an option...

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether you drop iOS 12 or not, you have to migrate your existing implementation to support the "new" CarPlay. It seems that iOS 15 devices cannot handle old `MPPlayableContent` implementations even though they *should* be backwards compatible (what I see is that the root list is presented but I cannot tap any row).

My app supports both `MPPlayableContent` and the new template style from the CarPlay framework. The key steps were:

- Add both CarPlay types to the entitlements (Xcode) and Additional Capabilities (under the app identifier on developer.apple.com)
- Add a scene delegate for CarPlay (i.e. `CarPlaySceneDelegate`) conforming to `CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate`
- Add a scene delegate for the App (i.e. `SceneDelegate`)
- Add a `UIApplicationSceneManifest` key to you info.plist and add entries for `CPTemplateApplicationSceneSessionRoleApplication` and `UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication` for the `UISceneConfigurations` (class names have to match your corresponding scene delegate class names)
- Move a bunch of code from application delegate functions to "shared" functions (i.e. logic from `application(_:open:options:)` and `scene(_:openURLContexts:)` is the same)
- implement application(_:configurationForConnecting:options:)
- Add bunch of `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` around the new apis
- weakly link the CarPlay framework
- The hard part: Reimplement CarPlay using the new CarPlay framework

See Apple sample code: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/integrating_carplay_with_your_music_app

More detail on the setup process:
https://medium.com/br-next/launching-br-radio-on-carplay-audio-8baab824b932

Comment: thanks. I'll give it a try.